React + TypeScript: Issue Displaying Backend Response on UI after Form Submission
I'm working on a React project with TypeScript, where I need to submit a query through a form, send it to the backend, and then display the response on the UI. I've set up the frontend and backend, but I'm having trouble displaying the response on the "/response/" route after the form submission.
Problem: After submitting the form, the response data is correctly received from the backend (confirmed via console logging), but it is not being displayed on the UI at the "/response/" route. The console shows the response as expected, but the page at "/response/" remains empty.
I need help understanding why the data is not being displayed on the screen and how I can properly render the response data on the "/response/" route.
Even though the response is correctly logged in the console, nothing is rendered on the "/response/" page.
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import SendIcon from "./icons/send";

interface FormData {
  onSubmit: (query: string) => void;
}

const Form: React.FC<FormData> = ({ onSubmit }) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onSubmit(query);
    // Navigate to the new page with the text "testing"
    navigate("/response/:id");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="max-w-3xl mx-auto mt-8 md:absolute md:bottom-0 md:left-0 md:right-0">
      <div className="relative flex items-center rounded-full border-gray-200 py-2">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={query}
          onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          className="appearance-none bg-[#F3F5F4] border-none w-full rounded-full text-gray-700 py-4 px-4 md:px-2 md:pl-4 md:ml-16 leading-tight focus:outline-none"
          required
        />

        <button
          type="submit"
          className="absolute right-0 mr-3 focus:outline-none"
        >
          <SendIcon />
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;



import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Efficiency from "./tables/efficiency";
import Dependency from "./tables/dependency";
import Complexity from "./tables/complexity";
import Learning from "./tables/learning";
import Maintenance from "./tables/maintenance";
import Form from "./form";

interface Prompt {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  response: string;
}

const prompts: Prompt[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Provide tech stack solutions for IoT Home Automation development",
    response: "Sure! Here are some tech stacks you can consider...",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Suggest an Authentication solution and evaluate it on a High, Medium, or Low scale",
    response:
      "I can present tables in markdown format, which is commonly used in documentation and can\n be easily rendered in many platforms. Here's an example",
  },
];

const ChatResponse: React.FC = () => {
  const [isExternalDependencyChecked, setIsExternalDependencyChecked] = useState(false);
  const [checkedCount, setCheckedCount] = useState(0);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const { id } = useParams<{ id?: string }>();

  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submitted query:", query);

    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/generate-solutions", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userID: "",
          requestID: "",
          modelParameter: { temperature: 0.9 },
          user_input: query,
          filters: ["complexity", "scalability", "cost", "dimensions", "time", "network", "diversity"],
          model_id: "anthropic.claude-3-haiku-20240307-v1:0",
          proposed_solution: "Your proposed solution here",
          tech_stack: "Your tech stack here"
        }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("Response data:", data);
        setResponse(data.proposed_solution);
      } else {
        console.error("Error submitting query:", response.statusText);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Network error:", error);
    }

    setSubmitted(true);
  }

  const prompt = id ? prompts.find((p) => p.id === parseInt(id, 10)) : undefined;

  if (!prompt) {
    return null;
  }

  const handleMaintenanceItemChecked = (itemName: string, isChecked: boolean) => {
    if (itemName === "Line of Code") {
      setIsExternalDependencyChecked(isChecked);
    }
    setCheckedCount((prevCount) => {
      const newCount = isChecked ? prevCount + 1 : Math.max(prevCount - 1, 0);
      return newCount;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className={`flex flex-col p-2 ${submitted ? "overflow-auto" : "overflow-hidden"}`}>
      <div className="p-2 bg-[#F3F5F4] rounded-full mb-2 md:mt-2 ml-auto">
        <div className="text-[16px] text-black mb-2">{prompt.text}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="p-4 bg-white mt-2 mx-auto max-w-4xl">
        <div className="text-black text-justify whitespace-pre-line py-2">{prompt.response}</div>
        <div className="text-black -mt-2">Filter table by</div>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-2 -mt-8">
          {/* First column for Maintenance and Efficiency */}
          <div className="flex flex-col space-y-2">
            <Maintenance onItemChecked={handleMaintenanceItemChecked} />
            <Efficiency />
          </div>
          {/* Second column for Dependency, Learning, and Complexity */}
          <div className="flex flex-col space-y-2 -ml-16">
            <Dependency
              initialChecked={isExternalDependencyChecked}
              onCheckedChange={(isChecked) => {
                setIsExternalDependencyChecked(isChecked);
                setCheckedCount((prevCount) => {
                  const newCount = isChecked ? prevCount + 1 : Math.max(prevCount - 1, 0);
                  return newCount;
                });
              } } />
            <Learning />
            <Complexity />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-1 bg-[#086224] text-white text-center mr-32 rounded-sm">
          <Link to={`/chat-markdown/${id}`} className="cursor-pointer">
          Click to filter ({checkedCount})
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div><form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={query} onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    
      {response && (
        <div className="p-4 bg-white mt-2 mx-auto max-w-4xl">
          <div className="text-black text-justify whitespace-pre-line py-2">
            {response}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatResponse;
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



enter code here


What is the "page at "/response/""? What/where is handling the request response in your frontend code? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with? I invite you to also take the full [tour] and review Help/How to Ask to learn additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

It would be nice to show the code's of /response route, where you are gonna show the data.

I’m a bit pressed for time and need to solve this quickly
I would really appreciate any insights you could share. Thank you so much in advance!

Hey @RouaaBelhajali did you found issue in this part of code?-
if (response.ok) {
const data = await response.json();
console.log("Response data:", data);
setResponse(data.proposed_solution);
}
